# Появление блока с задержкой (через время)

Tags: html, css

Есть 2 блока `<div class="hide_block1"></div>` он по умолчанию открытый и блок `<div class="hide_block2"></div>`- по умолчанию скрытый, как сделать так, чтобы он появился через 3 секунды?

```css
   .hide_block1 {
  background: green;
   width: 200px;
   height: 120px;
}
.hide_block2 {
  display: none;
  background: red;
   width: 200px;
   height: 120px;
   transition: 3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="hide_block1"></div>
<div class="hide_block2"></div>
```

Comment: Тут поможет `animation` вместо `transition` https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Ispolzovanie_CSS_animatciy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант с использованием css анимации

[Поддержка браузерами](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)

```css
.hide_block1 {
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
}
.hide_block2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 0px;
  animation: showDiv 3s forwards;
}
@keyframes showDiv {
  0%, 99% {
    height: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 120px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hide_block1"></div>
<div class="hide_block2"></div>
```

Вариант 2

```css
.hide_block1 {
    background: green;
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
}

.hide_block2 {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    animation: showDiv 3s forwards;
}

@keyframes showDiv {
    0%,
    99% {
        max-height: 0;
    }
    100% {
        max-height: 999px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="hide_block1"></div>
<div class="hide_block2">Есть 2 блока по умолчанию скрытый, как сделать так, чтобы он появился через 3 секунды? Есть 2 блока по умолчанию скрытый, как сделать так, чтобы он появился через 3 секунды? Есть 2 блока по умолчанию скрытый, как сделать так, чтобы он появился через 3
    секунды? Есть 2 блока по умолчанию скрытый, как сделать так, чтобы он появился через 3 секунды? </div>
```

Comment: это если точно известна высота

Comment: добавил вариант с неизвестной высотой

Comment: по моему без js это - как то не так выглядит

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать [JavaScript setTimeout](http://javascript.ru/settimeout), для того, чтобы выполнить код с задержкой (через время). Этот метод выполняет код(или функцию), указанный в первом аргументе, асинхронно, с задержкой в `delay` миллисекунд (в нашем случае `delay = 3000 миллисекунд = 3 секунды`). `setTimeout` выполняет код только один раз:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
   document.getElementById('hideBlock').style.display = 'block';
}, 3000);
```

```css
.hide_block1 {
  background: green;
   width: 200px;
   height: 120px;
}
.hide_block2 {
  display: none;
  background: red;
   width: 200px;
   height: 120px;
   transition: 3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="hide_block1"></div>
<div class="hide_block2" id='hideBlock'></div>
```